# Java HttpsURLConnection outbound limit?

Tags: java, https

I am creating a test app to load test a comet servlet by creating a bunch of outbound https connections (each looping in its own thread).

Is there a limit on the number of concurrent outbound http requests? If so, is it an OS level issue (xp 32bit) or Java?  I get the following exception when running around 100 connections. The error does not occur instantly but after anywhere between 50-150 loops (sometimes more), leading me to suspect that it actually might be me not releasing resources correctly:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
    at         com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:916)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1177)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
 at fqexconnectiontesting.FQEXHttpClient.run(FQEXHttpClient.java:158)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My code:

```
while(true){
try{                    
connection =(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();                    
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("keep-alive", "true");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
input = new DataInputStream( connection.getInputStream() ); 
b = new byte[4096];                    
totalBytes += input.read(b);                    
input.close();
b = null;         
connection.disconnect();                                        
connection = null;
Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks,
Dazz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Java opens only up to 5 persistent connections to the same host.
But your code uses the disconnect() method which AFAIK prevents persistent connections.

You should better read the documentation about [Persistent Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html). Take the sample code near the end for getting a fully working persistent connection.

May be this fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks, the disconnect appears to be required. What solved it was setting the http.maxConnections up to higher number.